# Pass value on click to thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, forms, class

so let's say i have 3 threads which run an instance from a class. The class will perform several task. When the class reached a point, it should open a window where the user can enter something, and on a button click the form will close and the thread should perform the last tasked with the value that the user entered.

1. Start 3 Thread. (Each thread has different values.)
2. Perform several task.
3. Open Window and wait for the input.
4. User enters some data and click "OK".
5. Thread get's the data and do some additional task.
6. Finished.

So, how can I pass the entered value to the thread / class?

Info: This is WPF, and not WinForms.

I look forward to some answers.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but... was there a question somewhere in your text?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Saw it already and added it.

Comment: Why can you not get the data from the user before the tread starts?

Comment: Because the programm will gather some data, and the user will have to choose what he want to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to place the data you need in some shared state then access that state from the other thread. When the form opens have the background thread wait on a WaitHandle & let the user interact with the form. When the user clicks Okay you first populate the shared state, then reset the WaitHandle. This will free up the background thread, which then reads the data from the shared state & continues with it's execution. Here's a basic sequence diagram

```
  Thread 1            Thread2
T0 -> Hits waitHandle
T1 -> blocked             Launches Form
T2 ->                     User interacts with form
T3 ->                     Okay clicked
T4 ->                     Shared state is populated
T5 ->                     WaitHandle reset
T6 -> Continues
T7 -> Reads shared state
```

The shared state will be located in the parent class for Thread1 & the form, and should be lock protected. There is tons of infomration on locking and WaitHandles, but [here's a great primer from Joe Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Comment: An alternative is for the thread instance to BeginInvoke itself to the GUI before waiting on some event.  The 'shared state' could then just be data members of the thread class.  There is no need for any locking since the GUI thread and work thread do not access the state at the same time.  You could OO-ise it all by a custom thread class with an abstract 'FormShow()' method that the GUI will call to display the form and, after close, signal some internal event to make the work thread run again.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx

And here is some text so my answer doesn't get automatically converted to a comment.